# Reduced Group algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Take a finite group and a field of characteristic zero. The group algebra is due to Maschke's theorem semisimple so that its a finite direct sum of matrix algebras over division algebras. I like to know when the case occurs that the decomposition is a direct sum of division algebras (such algebras are called reduced which is equivalent to that there are no nilpotent elements). Clearly this is the case when the group is abelian. Is there any other example?

In the case of rational group algebras over dihedral and quanternion groups there is always a matrix algebra involved.

Of course in the case of complex numbers the answer is also no.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The real group algebra of the quaternion group of order $8$ is the direct sum of $4$ copies of the real field and one copy of the $4$-dimensional division algebra of real quaternions.

Later edit : Here is a  proof of the claim that a finite group $G$ with a reduced group algebra $KG$ for $K$ a field of characteristic zero is Hamiltonian. By induction, we may suppose that $G/N$ is Hamiltonian whenever $1 \neq N \lhd G.$

Suppose first that $G$ has a unique minimal normal subgroup $M.$ Then $G$ has a  faithful irreducible $KG$-module $V$, and $G$ embeds in the multiplicative group of a division algebra. Now every Sylow subgroup of $G$ is cyclic or generalized quaternion, and if $G$ has even order, then $G$ has a unique involution. If $G$ has odd order, then $G$ has a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup for some prime $p.$ In all cases, $M$ must be cyclic of prime order, $q$ say. Now $C_{G}(M)$ is nilpotent, as $G/M$ is nilpotent. Let $r$ be a prime divisor of $[G:C_{G}(M)].$ Then $r$ divides $q-1$, and all subgroups of $G$ of order $qr$ are Abelian by a result of Burnside. Hence $C_{G}(M)$ contains a cyclic subgroup of order $qr$ containing $M.$ Since $G/M$ is Hamiltonian, this subgroup is normal in $G,$ so $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $r$. This contradicts the fact that $M$ is the unique minimal normal subgroup of $G.$ Hence $M \leq Z(G),$ and $G$ is nilpotent.

If $G$ has two minimal normal subgroups $L$ and $T,$ then $G/L$ and $G/T$ are both nilpotent, and hence so is $G.$

In any case, then, $G$ is nilpotent, and all minimal normal subgroups of $G$ are central, and of prime order. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ which is not normal. Then $H$ is corefree, for if $C = \cap_{g \in G}H^{g},$ and $C \neq 1,$ then $G/C$ is Hamiltonian and $H \lhd G.$

Let $x \in H$ be of prime order. Then whenever $1 \neq N \lhd G,$ we have that $xN \in Z(G/N)$. Hence $[G, \langle x \rangle ] \leq N.$ Hence $G$ must indeed have a unique minimal normal subgroup, for otherwise $x \in Z(G),$ a contradiction. Since $G$ is nilpotent, $G$ is now a $q$-group for some prime $q.$ Also, $G$ embeds in the multiplicative group of a division algebra, so $G$ is cyclic or generalized quaternion.
Hence we may suppose that $q =2,$ and that $G$ is generalized quaternion. If $|G| >8,$ then $G$ has a dihedral group of order $8$ as a homomorphic image, a contradiction, as a dihedral group of order $8$ is not Hamiltonian. Hence $G$ is either cyclic or quaternion of order $8,$ and the proof is complete.

Comment: Thanks for your example, in characteric p this is not possible as answered in " The division algebras arising in the Wedderburn decomposition of a finite group modulo its radical in characteristic p". Modulo the radical their are only fields as division algebras, such that in this case KG is reduced if and only if KG is solvable. Do you know when in charcteric zero only fields and division algebras occur?

Comment: Yes, indeed, this can't happen in characteristc $p.$ I think that in characteristic $p,$ we obtain that $KG/J(KG)$ is reduced if and only if $G/O_{p}(G)$ is Abelian ( here, I assume that $K$ is finite), which is slightly different from what you say. Returning to characteristic $0,$ I think there are no examples other than Hamiltonian groups, but I need to check that.

Comment: Hi Geoff, when you look at the proof of " The division algebras arising in the Wedderburn decomposition of a finite group modulo its radical in characteristic p" there is no need for a finte field, it looks like that is valid in positive characterics for all fields! I will check again against the qotet excercis in Isaacs character theory book. If you have a proof in characteristic zero that would be a nice result on "recuded" group algebras. I have searched for it in the net but did not find anything in this direction... KR Sven

Comment: Hi Geoff, thanks for your feedback. I will read your proof carefully and come back to you for further questions if needed. Many thanks Sven

Comment: I have the following questions to your proof after a first review: Why is there a minimal normal subgroup and G cannot be simple? Why is in your proof M unique (is otherwise G nilpotent?) and why is M cylic (maybe based on the structure of G using Albert theorem?)?

Comment: You can proceed in several ways for your first question: the only non-solvable Frobenius complement is known too be ${\rm SL}(2,5)$ which is not simple, but you don't need the full strength of that.

Comment: @Sven: I think I have now corrected the proof.

Comment: Yes, indeed, very well now. I think one should add some more things for understanding: At the beginning that G cannot be simple; for the faithful repre. there we use char(F)=0, since the regular repre. is not faithful otherwise (as it decomposes into the irre. ones); following the structure of the embedded group (is this Amitsurs result?)

Comment: @Sven: The regular representation is always faithful, I don't think you said what you meant. It was Amitsur who classified the finite groups which can be embedded in division algebras, but several general structure theorems were known before that. Burnside already knew that finite Abelian subgroups of division algebras had to be cyclic, and that subgroups of order $qr$ had to be cyclic when $q$ and $r$ were distinct primes ( in fact, he went on to make further erroneous conclusions which were corrected later by others).

Comment: My note was related to the implication: Suppose first that G has a unique minimal normal subgroup M. Then G has a faithful irreducible KG-module. Assume that is not the case. Then the minimal subgroup is in the kernel of all irreducibiles and the regular repre. would not be faithful.

Comment: While I was studying your excellent proof I got an idea which might gives the proof another direction. For a subset $U$ of the finite group $G$ define $e_U:=\frac{1}{\mid U \mid} \sum_{u\in U}u$. Then its easy to verify that $e_U$ is an idempotent iff $U$ is a subgroup. In addition $U$ is a normal subgroup iff $e_U$ is a central idempotent. By the assumption that $KG$ is reduced we can see that every subgroup of $G$ is a normal subgroup. So $G$ must be Hamiltonian. Now its a task to conclude that in the non-abelian case only $Q_8$ is valid...

Comment: If $F$ is a field of $char(F)=0$ and $FQ_8$ reduced, then is for every $n\in \mathbb{N}_0$ the group algebra $F(Q_8\times(Z_2)^n)$ reduced as well. This group algebra decomposes into several direct copies of $FQ_8$ and is reduced as well.

Comment: I am not sure about that, which is why I had to rewrite my proof. I do not think that the group algebra $F(Q_{8} \times Q_{8})$ is reduced. It you factor out the diagonal of the centre of $Q_{8},$ then you get an extraspecial group of order $32$ which is not Hamiltonian and does not have a reduced group algebra. I am not sure of the status of $Q_{8}$ direct product an elementary Abelian $2$-group.

Comment: Yes, $F(Q_8 \times Q_8)$ is not reduced since $Q_8 \times Q_8$ is not Hamiltonian. The group algebra $F(Q_8\times (Z_2)^n)$ is isomorphic to $FQ_8 \otimes FZ_2 \otimes ... \otimes FZ_2$. Since $FZ_2$ is isomorphic to $F\times F$ we get several copies of the group algebra $FQ_8$, and so $F(Q_8\times (Z_2)^n)$ is reduced as well (if $FQ_8$ is, that is $F$ is not a splitting field for $Q_8$).

Comment: I think we have to investigate now $F(Q_8\times (Z_2)^n\times A)$ for an abelian group of odd degree. As $FQ_8$ decomposes into $F^4\times L$ and $L$ is a quaternion over $F$, it should not happen that in the decomposition of $KA$ a splitting field of $Q_8$ appears ($L\otimes K$ is a quaternion over $K$ for such a field appearing in the decomposition of $KA$). Otherwise we have a matrix-algebra appearing. What do you think, Geoff? How does this restrict $A$?

Comment: Hi Geoff, I have searched a little bit and have found an article about Reversible group rings from Marin Gutan and Andrzej Kisielewicz. Such a group ring is reversible iff for all $a,b\in KG$ from $ab=0$ we can deduce $ba=0$. There is a complete classification involved in $char(K)=0$ (Theorem 5.1). In the case of $char(K)=0$ I could show that $KG$ is reduced iff $KG$ is reversible. In Theorem 5.1 it is shown that for $K$ the equation $x^2+y^2+1=0$ must be no solution in any cyclotomic field extension $L=K[w_n]$ of $K$ for every odd $n$ which is an order of an element of $G$.

Comment: @SvenWirsing: Thanks for that information.

Comment: I will invenstigate now the proof for the $char(K)=p>0$ - case. If its valid that all division algebras in the wedderburn-decompositon of $KG/rad(KG)$ are fields then in this case $KG$ is reduced iff KG is soluble. Hence we have a complete description of reduceg group algebras over finite groups and fields...

Comment: I am really astonished that in the modular case shows that all division algebras arising in the decomposition of $KG/rad(KG)$ are fields. Do you know whether there is a name for such algebras?

Comment: Is that such a surprise? Finite division algebras are fields, and you can take a finite field $K$ as splitting field for the finite group $G.$ I confess that I have never really considered what happens if we pass to the algebraic closure.

Comment: I also admit that I do not understand your claim (in the modular case) that the semisimplification of group algebra of a solvable groups is reduced- but this may be my ignorance.

Comment: Yes, thats surprise me that even for infinite big fields its still true. Hm, if $KG/rad(KG)$ is always iso. (in the modular case) to full matrix algebras over fields, then this factor-algebra is reduced iff it decomposes into fields. By definition these algebras are called soluble (also in the associative case). They are classified for group algebras (in the modular case) that the $p$-Sylowsubgroup is normal haveing an abelian Hall-complement.